# Different behavior when using JOptionPane in Windows7 vs OS X

Tags: java, user-interface, artifacts

Whenever I run the below code on a Windows 7 machine, I get odd artifacts above one of the buttons.

Typically it's a straight line above whatever button is highlighted by default and as tab over the other buttons I get a straight line above the other buttons as well.

It also looks like I get a line at the very top of the Window.  When I've witnessed these same artifacts before in different java UI's I've worked on I've had to do `object.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.someMatchingColor))`.  This obviously isn't an option if I'm doing the JOptionPane method.

Is there some known issue with java?

```
public class TestProj {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InstantiationException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Test");
   }
}
```

Comment: On which platform do you get this problem?  Do you have a screen shot?  Make sure you are running within the context of the EDT, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a screenshot with me since it's happening on a work computer and I'm home.  But the problem happens on the Windows 7 platform.

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me, Windows 7, Java 1.7.51

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for trying.  I'll take a screen shot tomorrow and post it up.  I tried multiple Windows 7 machines and had the same result (they were Windows 7 vm's, but different builds of Windows 7 - not sure if that makes a difference or not).